# Bitrix вывести свойство привязанное к элементу

Tags: php, битрикс, cms

Привет Всем, нужно вывести свойство привязанное к элементу,в моем случае выводится id к которому привязан элемент.
Вопрос в том, как вывести значения самого свойства а не значения элемента к которому он привязан ?

вот код

```
        if ($arFields['IBLOCK_ID'] == 9) {  
            $ID = $arFields['ID'];
            $arSelect = Array("PROPERTY_DATETIME", "PROPERTY_USER", "PROPERTY_CLINIC", "PROPERTY_DOCTORS");
            $arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID"=>9, "ACTIVE_DATE"=>"Y", "ACTIVE"=>"Y", "ID" => $ID);
            $res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, false, $arSelect);
            if ($res->SelectedRowsCount() == 1) {
                if ($GLOBALS['compare']["ID"] == $ID) {
                    while($ob = $res->Fetch()){
                        // Получаем новую дату
                        $date_time = $ob['PROPERTY_DATETIME_VALUE'];
                        $clinic = $ob['PROPERTY_CLINIC_VALUE'];
            //вот тут выводится не само свойствао а id привязанного
                        $doctors = $ob['PROPERTY_DOCTORS_VALUE'];

                        $user = getUserLoginById($ob['PROPERTY_USER_VALUE']);
                        $user_lang = getUserLangById($ob['PROPERTY_USER_VALUE']);
                        $user_id =  $ob['PROPERTY_USER_VALUE'];


                    }
    }
    }
    }

// тут как-то получают логин по id,надо что - то вроде этого вероятно
        function getUserLoginById($userID){
            $userID = (int)$userID;
            $rsUser = CUser::GetByID($userID);
            $arUser = $rsUser->Fetch();
            return $arUser['LOGIN'];
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

GetById 
https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/getbyid.php

там уже выбираешь свойства, которые надо выводить

Comment: а можно пример коротенький ? Ато я в битриксе нуб, но приходится поддерживать чужой код как-то.

наверх добавил пример, как по id номер телефона получают, что там добавить или изменить чтобы получить id, был бы очень сильно благодарен

Comment: Если id в $doctors, то                                                                        
$res = CIBlockElement::GetByID($doctors);
if($ar_res = $res->GetNext()) {
  print_r($ar_res);
}    в массиве $ar_res значения свойств привязанного эл-та. Из него выбираешь нужное

Comment: сделал как вы сказали, массив $ar_res пуст к сожалению..

Comment: это понятно, но дело в том что элемент который нужно получить по id находится в другом разделе инфоблока, а вызвать его надо в одном

Comment: это не тот ответ который мне нужен к сожалению

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так

```
function loadDoctors($doctor_ids = [])
{
    $arDoctors = [];
    $res = \CIBlockElement::GetList(
        [],
        ['ID' => $doctor_ids],
        false,
        false,
        ['ID', 'NAME']
    );
    while($doctor = $res->GetNextElement())
    {
        $arDoctors[] = $doctor->GetFields();
    }
    return $arDoctors;
}
```

Желательно проверять также на пустое значение докторов.